# Cannot select vertices of any object In blender, while in edit mode and using Archipack

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, archipack-add-on

So, Im making a course on Archipack (add on for architecture and building houses), and Im trying to select vertices then put the cursor on the selection position, and therefore I can add the window through the Archipack menu.

It enables me to select the windows on the Outliner menu, but when I enter edit mode and enable vertex mode, I cannot select any vertices even though there are 2 vertices selected by default, inclusive putting lasso tool or any other type of selection. I've restarted blender twice, and I don't know what kind of problem it may be, considering my mouse is a brand new one (HP) and I also checked its battery.

Please don't say me that my file is corrupted or something...

Thanks in advance for your help,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Blender to 2.91 and I already can select the vertices again, but if you manage to give another solution I have 2.90 as well so another person can find an answer to this problem.